# How to register Scala UDF in spark-SQL, not Spark-Scala?

Tags: scala, hive, apache-spark-sql

It looks like a regular Hive statement should work. In my script.sql which I run through `spark-sql --jars mylib.jar myscript.sql`

```
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION rank AS 'com.mycompany.udf.Custom.rankFunc';

...
CREATE TEMPORARY VIEW MyTable AS (
    SELECT
       rank(id)  AS rank,
       ...
```

In Scala code (mylib.jar):

```
package com.mycompany.udf

...

object Custom {
    def rankFunc(id: Long): Double = { Rank(id).rank }
    ....
}
```

However, Hive code does not see this function.

```
18/01/23 17:38:25 ERROR SparkSQLDriver: Failed in [
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION rank AS 'com.mycompany.udf.Custom.rankFunc']
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mycompany.udf.Custom.rankFunc
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
```

How should I change the code in my Scala library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting this error because Hive expects a function to be a *class*, not a method name.

Change your Scala code (UDF) to:

```
package com.mycompany.udf

class RankFunc extends org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.UDF {
  def evaluate(id: Long): Double = { Rank(id).rank }
}
```

... and SQL script to:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION rankFunc AS 'com.mycompany.udf.RankFunc'
...
```

Here are examples of how to create a custom UDF with [Java](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HivePlugins) and [Scala](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/42695/how-to-create-a-hive-udf-in-scala.html).

Answer (score 0):

Because there is lots of confusion I am updating my answer:

here is the code for md5 jave code:

```
package org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf;
import org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Description;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.UDF;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.BytesWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;

public class UDFMd5 extends UDF {
  private final Text result = new Text();
  /**
   * Convert String to md5
   */
  public Text evaluate(Text n) {
    if (n == null) {
      return null;
    }
    String str = n.toString();
    String md5Hex = DigestUtils.md5Hex(str);
    result.set(md5Hex);
    return result;
  }  
}
```

I have taken the same jar used in Hive and was able to make it work :

[image]

AND This worked for me :

[image]

In hive i used :

> create temporary function md5 AS
>   'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.UDFMd5' USING JAR
>   '/test/balaram/hive-MD5.jar;

In Spark I used :

> create temporary function md5 AS
>   'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.UDFMd5'

If This doesn't help, I am sorry

Comment: yeah, I know how to do that with Spark. My question is about spark-sql.

Comment: You need to include the jar when starting your Spark SQL. You can use like below :

CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION myFunnyUpper AS 'org.hue.udf.MyUpper'

Comment: Right. That's what I did in the code above. Also, I used a jar - updated in the question. But it does not work.

Comment: I have edited above post to show how I was able to make it work.

Comment: Could you please clarify? Where do you run `sqlContext.udf.register("customudf", ..) `? I don't have `main()` in my jar.